# Button with text label: How do I keep the hover color even when over text label?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to create a button with a text label, and I want both the button and the label to respond to a click, and, I want a hover color.  This code works except that I lose the hover color when over the text label.  What do I need to add or do differently to keep the hover color when over the text label?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
#resetButton {
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: #FFF68F;
}
#resetButton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: #FFFF00;
}
</style>
<div id = "main"> </div>
<script src = "http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"> </script>
<script>
var svg = d3.select('#main')
    .append('svg')
var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr({id: "resetButton"})
g.append('circle') // reset button
  .attr({cx: 100, cy: 100, r: 25})
  .attr({id: "resetButton"})
  .attr({onclick: "doSomething()" })
g.append('text') // button label
  .attr({x: 100, y: 95})
  .attr({fill: "black"})
  .attr({"font-size":  20})
  .attr({"text-anchor": "middle"})
  .text('R')
  .attr({onclick: "doSomething()" })
doSomething = function() {
  alert("Reset")
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off pointer events for your text element.

```
g.append('text') // button label
  .attr({"pointer-events": "none"})
  ...
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/YDd2L/)

Comment: Thanks... I would have never found that attribute!